# Anidar media queries con CSS

Tags: html, html5, css3

Estoy dandole vueltas al tema de anidar varios media queries dentro de uno solo, algo asi como:

```
@media (width: 1024px){
  @media (heigth:300px){
     //codigo
  }

  @media (heigth:600px){
     //codigo
  }
}
```

Seria posible o habría que hacerlo de este tipo:

```
@media (width: 1024px) and (height: 300px){
   //codigo
}


@media (width: 1024px) and (height: 600px){
   //codigo
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Si miramos en las **[especificaciones de CSS3](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-conditional/#processing)**, hay una sección en la que trata este tema. Lo llaman `Processing of conditional group rules`.

Según el ejemplo que provee la especificación (traducción propia):

> Por ejemplo, con este conjunto de reglas anidadas:
>
> ```
> @media print { // rule (1)
>   /* hide navigation controls when printing */
>   #navigation { display: none }
>   @media (max-width: 12cm) { // rule (2)
>     /* keep notes in flow when printing to narrow pages */
>     .note { float: none }
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> la condición de la regla marcada (1) es verdadera para medios impresos, y la condición de la regla marcada (2) es verdadera cuando la anchura del área de impresión (que para medios impresos es el cuadro de página) es menor a o igual a 12cm. Por lo tanto, la regla ‘#navigation { display: none }’ se aplica siempre que esta hoja de estilos se aplique a medios impresos, y la regla ‘.note { float: none }’ es aplicada solo cuando la hoja de estilos es aplicada a medios impresos y la anchura del cuadro de la página es menor que o igual a 12 centímetros.

**NOTA IMPORTANTE:** Recuerda que el orden de los media queries es importante y, por lo tanto, tienen que ir de menos a más resctrictivo en orden descendente (el orden de CSS). Es decir, si tienes un `max-width` de 600px como restricción y otro de 400px debería ir en primer lugar el de 600px.

Answer (score 0):

Hasta donde yo se **no se pueden anidar**. Tendrías que usar la segunda forma y la sintaxis tampoco es correcta, ***se indica si son medidas máximas o  mínimas junto con el ancho o el alto***. Por ejemplo:

```
@media (max-height: 900px) and (max-width: 500px) {
    /* Tu CSS aquí */
}
```

Puedes mirar tutoriales sobre el uso de media-queries como estos:
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/CSS/Media_queries
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp